# Moving big apps to SD card on 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, app2sd

My Android is 4.4.2, Phone model: Panasonic eluga s.

I have a 32 GB SD card in my cell. Please tell me how to shift big apps to SD card. I also have root access. There is no option of move to SD card on *Settings › Apps Manager* Any app chosen.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [app2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) for the basics?

Comment: If you have root, than use app called link2sd, I would post link but I can't open store idk why.